# Importing statsmodels.api gives import error

Tags: python, windows, statsmodels

I run `WinPython-64bit-2.7.10.3` and `WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.4Qt5` on Windows 7.

Yesterday I run statsmodels for the first time. It worked fine. Today it doesn’t.

After: `import statsmodels.api as ap` I just get `ImportError: No module named api` in 2.7.
In 3.4 I get `ImportError: No module named 'statsmodels.api'; 'statsmodels' is not a package`.

I have checked so that the package is installed. All other packages seem to work.

Comment: the 3.4 error message sounds like a local file/module called `statsmodels.py` that shadows the package. Make sure you don't have modules or scripts on the local python path with the same name as a package.

Comment: Head on. Thanks a lot.